# Where to configure listening port for a local web api

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a Wep Api project with .net core 3.1 created in VS 2019. For testing I deploy it to a local directory and started the exe from the doployed folder. See [Deploy an app to a local folder using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/visualstudio/deployment/quickstart-deploy-to-local-folder?view=vs-2019). Thats works fine, but the api listen always on the port  5000/50001

```
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5000 
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
```

Where to change the port? Settings in Properties/launchSettings.json of the project seems to have no affect (used only for debugging from VS)?

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5101",

      "sslPort": 5101
    }
  },
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "commandLineArgs": "Authority=http://localhost:5100",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "Api": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5101;http://localhost:5101"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *to a local directory and started the exe from the dopleyed folder*:

That's because you're starting a Kestrel server and by default it use `5000/5001`. Usually, instead call it `depoly`, we use the term `publish`. `Deploy` means deploy it to some server and interact with IIS/nginx. While `publish` means generate the executable files.

If you want to change the port, you can change the `appsettings.{env}.json`, add a `urls` as below:

```
{
    "urls": "http://localhost:8800",
    ...
```

Or if you want to override `8800` dynamically, just pass an argument of `--urls` by:

```
yourapp.exe --urls=https://localhost:8822
```